# Change Banktransfer template only for Onepage Checkout Progress Bar

Tags: onepage-checkout

On Onepage checkout, the progress bar also contains the detailed information for the payment method bank transfer, which is located in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/info/banktransfer.phtml`. We do not need this information, so i want to delete it.

When i modify this template to only show the payment title, also the payment information block on the order confirmation mail is affected, which is not intended.

How can i change the banktransfer template for progress bar only?

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: Or i ask another question: How can i check in the template if the template is currently used on the webpage (checkout process) or in an email?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the file `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Banktransfer.php` to your local folder (`app/code/local/...`) and change the method:

```
public function getInstructions()
{
    if (is_null($this->_instructions)) {
        $this->_instructions = $this->getInfo()->getAdditionalInformation('instructions');
        if(empty($this->_instructions)) {
            $this->_instructions = $this->getMethod()->getInstructions();
        }
    }
    return $this->_instructions;
}
```

to

```
public function getInstructions()
{
    return null;
}
```

It seems this block is only used in the progress block.